# Ssh over wifi drops the network

Tags: ssh, wifi, ethernet

I'm Italian so sorry if my english isn't that good.

I've bought for a week a new Raspberry Pi B+ and a wifi dongle Edimax ew-7811un. I've configured the /etc/network/interfaces and the /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf files and now the RasPi can connect to the Internet without problems with a static ip. When I try to connect my mac to the RasPi with ssh over the wifi I can establish the connection but if I write a command in my terminal the whole wifi network drops for all the connected devices in the house and after 30 seconds restarts. Then I tried to connect the RasPi to the internet with an Ethernet cable after I plugged out the dongle and then i could connect my mac with ssh without problems. But I need to have the RasPi connected only via wifi and not with the ethernet cable. So how can I solve? Thanks in advance :)

This is my interfaces file:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.115
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.1
broadcast 192.168.255
gateway 192.168.1.1

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet static
address 192.168.1.115
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
network 192.168.1.1
broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

And this is the wpa_supplicant.conf file:

```
    ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
    update_config=1

    network={
            ssid="secret-ssid"
            psk="secret-psk"
            proto=WPA
            key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
            pairwise=TKIP
            auth_alg=OPEN
    }
```

Comment: Congratulations, you built a wlan bomb! - please post the relevant lines form `dmesg` output

Comment: What do you mean with relevant? Which lines should I post? I've never used that command so I don't know what I should search for.

Sorry and thanks for the answer :)

Comment: try `dmesg | grep wlan0`

Comment: btw, is using `wicd-curses` an option for you? its pretty good on guessing the right configuration... Here is a (random) tutorial if your interested: http://blog.ubidots.com/setup-wifi-on-raspberry-pi-using-wicd

Comment: @FlorianFida `dmesg | grep wlan0` doesn't give a response and ￼with `wick-curses` I can't connect

Comment: try `zgrep 'wlan\|wpa_' /var/log/syslog*`

Comment: @FlorianFida there are a lot of `Aug 14 20:01:15 SimoPi wpa_supplicant[1701]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 00:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (SSID='my-ssid' freq=2437 MHz)
Aug 14 20:01:15 SimoPi wpa_supplicant[1701]: wlan0: Association request to the driver failed
Aug 14 20:01:15 SimoPi wpa_supplicant[1701]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx reason=0` and sometimes `Aug 14 09:40:05 SimoPi ifplugd(wlan0)[1680]: Link beat lost.` and a lot of other lines

Comment: are you sure you have a successful before that events happens?Can you connect via ssh from remote? `Association request to the driver failed` sounds like association never happened...

Comment: btw: did you try using a fresh image, or other hardware (wlan stick/keyboard) ?  
  
Do you have another linux machine on wlan or another image/distro which works for your raspberry pi where you can run `wpa_cli status`?

Comment: @FlorianFida I can connect via ssh from my mac because the output that I posted was taken from the terminal of my mac connected to the Pi via ssh. I wrote the command got the output and the wifi dropped. Could it be that the router is overloaded? I think it could be, but it's strange that via ethernet i don't get any problem :\ I'll try with a fresh image cause I don't have another hardware.

Comment: On my mac with the command `wpa_cli status` I get the following output:

`Selected interface 'wlan0'
bssid=00:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
ssid=my-ssid
id=0
mode=station
pairwise_cipher=TKIP
group_cipher=TKIP
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_state=COMPLETED
ip_address=192.168.1.115
address=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`